# Rock Shox Recon does not "completely" lock

Tags: mountain-bike, fork, suspension

I recently bought the 29er CUBE ACID 2017 equipped with a RockShox Rrecon front fork (Silver TK AIR PopLock 100mm).

I have noticed that even when the suspension is locked, there is still a movement (compression) of the stanchions of about 20mm. It is not completely rigid, not locked, even though the knob and the crown of the fork is in the LOCK position.

Is it supposed to work like this (as the shop I bought the bike from tells me) or is it somehow faulty? I am new with bicycles and I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 7):

RockShox FAQ FRONT SUSPENSION Remotes/Lock Outs:

> Why Isn’t The Lockout Function Completely Locked, Instead, There’s A 
>   Bit Of Travel?
>   Please know the lockout setting on most RockShox forks is not a “hard 
>   lockout”- meaning you will have about an inch of movement when the
>   fork is the locked mode. We call this feature Small Bump Compliance, 
>   and the intention is that the wheel will continue to track over 
>   ground with control, even in the locked setting.

Comment: Good answer. I just edited format to be in line with common practice here. Adding a link to the FAQ would be good too.

Answer (score 1):

Oil damped forks lock out by closing a valve and stopping the flow of oil through the damper.

The amount of lockout is usually adjustable by changing just how closed this valve is. But I can't find this anywhere in the manuals for your forks.

It is possible that it's factory set, how much force are you using to get the fork to move the 20mm you mentioned?

There is also a blow off valve for big hits, you could be activating that if you're jumping on it.

If you can pedal standing up without it bobbing around excessively then the lockout is working as expected, if not it could mean an oil leak or that the forks came under filled.

Answer (score 0):

The loose range of 20 mm i saw it also in a (2015) **3 years old** Rockshox with remote control. in a **new** Rockshox Fork with not remote its a lot better, the range is still there but not that loose(here at home).  Loose forks are a wasting energy device on uphill. I have a Marzzochi bomber without this "tracking feature" cos it does lock pretty well, also the Fork on my Stumpy 2011 used to lock for years very good. My gravel with rigid Fork do not miss this "small bump compliance". How many users do speedy uphill on rocky surface? if i need it i just unlock the fork and thats it. i smell a rat on that lock failure.